# Format textbox with numbers OnfocusOut / OnBlur

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a usercontrol Textbox that only allows numbers:

```
<it:CurrencyTextBoxControl_v2
      ID="txtCreditLimit" IsRequired="true"
      ShowCurrency="true"
      DecimalPlaces="2"
      OnBlur="formatNumbers();"
      CssClass="txtBoxCSS txtBoxCurrency"
      Label="<%$FrontEndResources:BackOffice,CreditOfLimit%>"
     runat="server" />`
```

All i want it to do is whenever you click outside of the textbox it formats the numbers like this: 
You enter: 10000000000 when you focus out it should appear: 100 000 000,00

every 3 numbers 1 space and the last two with a "," (comma) or a "." (dot)

Any idea? thanks in advance.

**Update**

I tried this:

```
formatCurrency() { $('#txtCreditLimit').mask("#.##0,00", { reverse: true }); }
```

but it says: 
"The object does not support property or method ' mask'"

Comment: i tried this: function formatCurrency() {
            $('#txtCreditLimit').mask("#.##0,00", { reverse: true });
        } but didn't work either

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what are you looking for

```
public string formatNumbers(){
    int n = Int32.Parse(txtCreditLimit.Text);
    return String.Format("{0:# ### ###.##}", n);
    }
```